# updating data on a webpage (with heavy leaflet.js chart)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, leaflet

What is the proper way to update a webpage with new datasets please. I have a webpage with a bootstrap navbar and a dropdown menu which I would like to use to select the dataset. When the webpage first opens it automatically loads one of these datasets. The problem is that when the webpage loads the very same dataset (this time from the dropdown menu) it crashes. The chart is a leaflet chart with a lot of markers (around 300K, which btw wouldnt have been possible without the help of a couple of ppl here!) but it works ok. When however as said earlier the same data are pushed again the browser chokes (it looks to me during the 'layer.on add' callback) and crashes.

I think (and that is a wild guess) this is leaflet related, maybe old data still live somewhere and arent getting dumped, but I dont really know.

That was with chrome but it happens with the other browsers as well. An outline of my code is shown below. (Note: in the snippet nothing is loaded on start-up, you will have to use the menu)

A browser refresh though works fine though.

How can I just clear everything from the webpage and start again (like a reload for instance) but passing my user-defined parameters. I hope it will work this way...

To put it in another way, I would like each time to remove all elements that were added to the webpage at a later stage (and remove associated objects from the memory as well) and then pass-in some parameters with the dropdown menu for example.

```js
function dispatcher(x){
    console.log('you clicked '+ x)
    cfg = config()
    run(cfg)
}

function config(){
    var ini = [

        {name: 'dataset-1', data:'some data 1'},
        {name: 'dataset-2', data:'some data 2'},

    ];
    var out = d3.map(ini, function (d) {return d.name;});
    return out
}

function run(config) {
    renderChart(config)
}


function renderChart(config) {
    console.log('Doing map')
    var mapStage = staging(config);
    var map = mapStage.map;
    console.log("doing some stuff with map and config")
}

function staging(){
    try {
        mapStage.map.off;
        mapStage.map.remove();
        console.log("map removed")
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        //do nothing
    }

    var map = L.map('mymap').setView([51.508530, -0.055], 12);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

    mapStage = []
    mapStage.map = map

    return mapStage
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Leaflet Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
</head>
<!--jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- d3 -->
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>

<!-- leaflet -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"> </script>

<script src="./example.js"> </script>

<body>
<input id="refresh" type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="renderChart();" />

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown" id="myDropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Select Data <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#" id = "dataset-1" onclick='dispatcher("dataset-1")'>Dataset 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" id = "dataset-2" onclick='dispatcher("dataset-2")'>Dataset 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->

    </div>
</div>
<div id="mymap" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the supplied code does not crash because you do nothing with it, (no layer.on add). Why create a new leaflet each time you load a dataset, only create the map when it is not there yet, you only need to remove the previous content and maybe set a new `.setView`

Comment: on my wide screen the navbar overlaps the map, and the collapse toggle is not visible `display:none`, I needed to remove the class `navbar-fixed-top`